# Writing Json files

Tags: python, json, data-analysis

-I am trying to get the results of multiple input files say I have 5 input files and the code generates 5 output files

- I could read the input files and generate the output files as well, but I got stuck in generating a specific json data I wanted. I will share the code the output files reads the **raw_data**, but I want the results to read **output_string**

I tried implementing the looping inside the main, i am just wondering is it in the right process?

```
def main():
    


    input_dir = "files"
    output_dir = "files1"
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
            # open input file
            with open(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), "r") as input_file:
                # load data from JSON file
                raw_data = json.load(input_file)

                processed_data =  raw_data * 2

                # output_file1 = os.path.join(output_dir, "merged_output.json")
                # save processed data to output file
                output_filename = filename.replace(".json", "_output.json")
                # output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)

                with open(os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename), "w") as output_file:
                    json.dump(processed_data, output_file)
                print(f"Files in {output_dir}: {os.listdir(output_dir)}")


    ## Calling Function 1
    # raw_data = ImporterFunction("9.json")



    ## Initialize lists to store the results of each sensor
    result = []

    ## Initialize lists to store the all the sensor data within a shipment
    sensor_df_complete = []

    ## Initialize lists to store the SesnorID and the Total Violation Duration
    sensor_ID_list = []
    sensor_Name = []
    total_Violation_Duration = []

    for record in raw_data:
        # for record in myList:

        ## Calling Function 1
        sensor_data_df, higher_threshold, lower_threshold, sensor_subID, sensorID, sensorName, min_threshold_duration, max_threshold_duration, data_recording_interval, start_UTC, end_UTC = ReadSensorData(
            record)

        if 6 >= sensor_subID > 3:

            print("Error - Sensor not in use !!!")

        else:


            ## Create the common parameters to the output
            json_data = {'Total_Number_of_Sensors': numberOfSensors,
                         'Total_Number_of_Violated_Sensors': numberOfViolatedSensors, 'StartUTC': start_UTC,
                         'EndUTC': end_UTC, 'All_Sensor_Mean': allSensorMean, 'All_Sensor_SD': allSensorSD,
                         'Result': result, 'Sensor_Vice_Total_Violation_Duration_Data': violation_list}

            output_string = json.dumps(json_data)


            
    return output_string

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #x = main()
    print(main())
```